# Debug cause of internal AnyLogic Errors/Exceptions

Tags: anylogic

is there any way to debug an error like this:

```
NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.anylogic.libraries.material_handling.EventExecutor$b.execute(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.b(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.nb(Unknown Source)
at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.k(Unknown Source)
```

Unfortunately there is no further information in the anylogic console. I have no clue where to start looking for the cause of the error. How can I find out which agent provoked this error?

Thanks!

Comment: upload your model somewhere and I'll try to check it out

Answer (score 0):

This is very rare and likely not caused by an agent. Hopefully, you have older versions that you can go back and check when the error first appeared? (Always keep a version history ;-) ).

If it just occurred now, just remove any changes you did previously to narrow your search